# Can't detach javascript event after it fires

Tags: javascript

I'm using this structure to create one-time click events:

```
function structure() {
    this.elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
    this.numElements = this.elements.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < this.numElements; i++) {
        this.elements[i].addEventListener('click', this.elementClicked.bind(this));
    }
}
```

The handler of those events is implemented as follows:

```
structure.prototype.elementClicked = function(e) {

    // ... processing event

    for(var i = 0; i < this.numElements; i++) {
        this.elements[i].removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee);
    }
};
```

The idea is to fire the handler once if any of the registered elements gets clicked, and then unregister the event from each of those elements

Unfortunately the handler still gets fired everytime I click on one of the registered items

I'm aware anonymous functions can't be used to reference the same object, but specifying arguments.callee or the entire name of the referenced function still didn't help the cause

Comment: `el.addEventListener('click', handler, {once: true})`, though browser support for the options object [is still ramping up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: `arguments.callee` refers to `elementClicked`, not to the bound function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to make your objects implement the *EventListener* interface. You can do this by adding a `handleEvent` method to the `.prototype` of the constructor, and then passing the object itself in place of the event handler.

```
function Structure() {
    this.elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
    this.numElements = this.elements.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < this.numElements; i++) { // v-- pass the object
        this.elements[i].addEventListener('click', this);
    }
}

// Implement the interface; gets invoked when an event occurs
Structure.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
  // Used a switch statement in anticipation of other event types
  switch (e.type) {
  case "click":
    this.elementClicked(e);
    break;
  }
};

Structure.prototype.elementClicked = function(e) {
    // ... processing event

    for(var i = 0; i < this.numElements; i++) { //    v-- pass the object
        this.elements[i].removeEventListener('click', this);
    }
};
```

Now there's no longer any need to use `.bind()`. Instead the value of `this` in `handleEvent` will be the bound object. You can still get the element to which the handler was bound via `e.currentTarget`.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call...

```
this.elements[i].addEventListener('click', this.elementClicked.bind(this));
```

... `bind` creates another instance of a method. It uses `this.elementClicked`, true, but otherwise is a completely different function. That's why you won't drop it with remoteEventListener called on `this.elementClicked`.

What's the workarounds? One possible option - passing `{ once: true }` as `addEventListener` param - has been given in the comments, but it's not supported by IE and Edge (and most likely won't be supported by the Safari you encounter in the nearest future). Here's another approach:

```
function Structure() {
    this.elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
    this.numElements = this.elements.length;

    // reassign a bound method onto instance:
    this.elementClicked = this.elementClicked.bind(this);

    for(var i = 0; i < this.numElements; i++) {
        this.elements[i].addEventListener('click', this.elementClicked);
    }
}

Structure.prototype.elementClicked = function(e) {

    // ... processing event
    for(var i = 0; i < this.numElements; i++) {
        this.elements[i].removeEventListener('click', this.elementClicked);
    }
};
```

Now you create a bound `elementClicked` method for each instance of `structure` object, having its context set permanently.